# Undergraduate Introduction to Modular Forms

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

What are the best introductory texts (or lecture notes) on modular forms aimed at an advanced undergraduate audience (for a student with a course in complex analysis and two courses in algebra and analysis each)?

Comment: You should also be aware of Milne's online notes.

Answer (score 5):

An extremely good textbook is, in my opinion, "A first course in modular forms" by F.Diamond & J.Shurman