# Elementary Lecture Note or Book on Modular Form for Beginner or Amateur or Self Study or Self Learning

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, modular-forms

I have searched and found a pdf file of Don Zagier, but having trouble to understand periodicity with Fourier function/transformation, Rieman Surface, lattice.

Can any one suggest me lecture notes or a book where things are explained more elaborately?
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805884/undergraduate-introduction-to-modular-forms) didn't help.

My purpose is to understand Modular Form in regard with number theory.

Comment: Hmm. You have picked a bad topic for elaborate explanations. This topic is normally tackled by graduate students.

Comment: @almagest please help, let me know the best possible notes/documents/books.

Comment: To understand how to make the modular curve into a Riemann surface (and what its field of meromorphic functions means, how the zeros/poles determinate it) you should look first at the Riemann sphere and the complex torus $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z})$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions

Comment: @reuns $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z})$ is a quotient ring ? Is Riemann surface mandatory to study modular form from number theoretic point of view?

Comment: $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z})$ is the quotient group (no ring there) which is locally isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$ so it makes sense to talk of meromorphic functions on it (they are just the doubly periodic meromorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}$)

Comment: Also I would say the modular forms are completely useless in their own. Their usefulness is to introduce a lot of new concepts and objects giving some important clues on many deep theorems and conjectures, connecting a lot of seemingly unrelated mathematical fields.

Comment: @reuns do you have any favorite expository article (regardless of difficulty)? Please suggest if you do.

Comment: Perhaps William A. Stein, _Modular Forms: A Computational Approach_?

Comment: The post to which you link in the body of the question – in what way was that unhelpful?

Comment: Anyway, how does this sound? https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/modular-functions-and-dirichlet-series-in-number-theory

Comment: @GerryMyerson not exactly unhelpful as a  non-math CS background person..I mean I was looking for more accessible literature,  F.Diamond's book is quite a popular book, but I will buy that if I don't have any other option... in the mean time I found Robeldo's book quite friendly but i have not reached at modular form of the book  yet... I will try your suggested  book, thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In general I hate Projective Space, Riemann surface !! as these are not usual and intuitive topics to read and I hav not found good expository articles on these, but these are also an integral part (I have been told, and read in Zaiger)... these are also concerning issues, most book barely explains them.

Comment: If you know some differential geometry and topology, Forster's book on Riemann surfaces is quite good, and to the point.